# Azure DevOps pipeline not recognizing pipeline variable in Bash script (not using a YAML file)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The Azure DevOps **pipeline** has this variable:

- Name: `pat`
- Value: Git repo authentication token

The pipeline has a Bash script task. It is set to filepath. Filepath is set to script.sh. script.sh begins with:

```
git clone https://username:$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo-name
```

Errors in pipeline logs:

```
PAT: command not found
Cloning into 'repo-name'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/healthcatalyst/CAP/_git/docs-template/'
```

To validate that the authentication token and repo URL are accurate, I can verify this works when run as inline code:

```
git clone https://username:$(pat)@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo-name
```

script.sh file is in repo-name.

However, **environment** variables work. Both of the following return the accurate value within the script. Note that one has no quotes and the other does.

```
echo $BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME
repo-name

echo "$BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME"
repo-name
```

Based on documentation I've seen (I am having difficulty with Microsoft's docs because I am not using a YAML file), I've tried unsuccessfully:

- `$pat`
- `$PAT`
- `$(PAT)`
- `"$(PAT)"`
- `gitToken=<backtick - Markdown is not allowing me to show a backtick here>echo $PAT<backtick>`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, all variables from the Library are unavailable in my bash script tasks :/

Comment: Just a hint, if your PAT variable is a secret variable; you have to pass it through the environment variables; MS doc states that the secret variables cannot be accessed from scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your PAT variable a secret variable ?

If so, then it's not directly accessible in script files

As you can see in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables

> Unlike a normal variable, they are not automatically decrypted into environment variables for scripts. You need to explicitly map secret variables.

Example:

```
...  
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(mySecret) # the recommended way to map to an env variable
```

Or if you are using the visual editor, like that:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use System.AccessToken instead of personal PAT:

```
git clone https://$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/company/project/_git/repo-name
```

To enable $SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: go to release page in ADO > Tasks > Agent job > check Allow scripts to access the OAuth token